Singular + (s) replace by plural
At the moment we write 'Remove material(s)', meaning it can be 1 or more materials that you remove. However, I don't really like the s between brackets. Also when you translate to French, you need to count with the gender of the noun, also in Dutch the translation is not one on one.
I was wondering if writing 'Remove materials' would be acceptable as solution.

It depends on where in the user interface the label is used. Maybe for a call-to-action it still makes sense, but I am thinking that if it is in a table column or confirmation message it might not be as clear. Can you provide a screenshot or mockup?

Translation solutions exist that support singular and plural translations based on a parameter. Can be a life saver if you have to do a lot of these types of translations.

It will be an extra step but it should be simple to add the conditional 'if single…' or plural for the correct translation. Counting selected items and displaying the right words should not be difficult.
